# python: записать структуру (несколько переменных разных типов) в бинарном виде в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловый-ввод-вывод, binary-file

Есть данные:

```
time = 0.1234 # 64 бит (double)
size = 123 # 32 бит
data = 345 # 32 бит
```

Необходимо записать их в бинарный файл. Т.е. надо записать 128 бит информации

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно выполнить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользуйтесь модулем [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

```
import struct

with open('/path/to/file', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(struct.pack("=dii", time, size, data))
```